# 300 TB dataset for LHC

Tags: research

Last week it was in the news that [LHC (Large Hadron Collider)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) research team has just released a 300 TB dataset. What is this dataset and how can I start experimenting with it?

Comment: A lot of information is available at the CERN website, for instance http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/cms-releases-new-batch-research-data-lhc, with tools and tutorials http://opendata.cern.ch/search?p=Run2011A%20collection%3ACMS-Tools to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.theverge.com/2016/4/25/11501078/cern-300-tb-lhc-data-open-access):

> The information is available for download in two formats: "primary
>   datasets" used by CERN researchers, and lightweight "derived datasets"
>   intended to be accessed by a wider audience.
>
> http://opendata.cern.ch/about/CMS